# Replace "),(" with "),\n(" in Linux

Tags: awk, sed, replace, ed

Hy everybody.

I have the following insert in a MySQL script file as an example that I obtained from `mysqldump` in Linux Ubuntu Server with no GUI.

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF),(AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF);
```

I'd like to replace the character `),(` with `),\n(` because parentheses are particular to replace.

How can I change the input `),(` to `),\n(`.

Comment: Please edit the question add input and expected output. Wrap the samples in code blocks with the `{}` button above the text field. Also add what you have tried or searched and how that failed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the bloks for the code., Quasimodo 3.

Comment: I was looking for the fix but I didn't obtained something well.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is not really that parentheses are problematic to deal with, but that newlines are sometimes difficult to insert in a text.

Using GNU `sed` (usually found on Linux systems): This simply replaces all occurrences of the string `),(` with `),\n(` (where `\n` is a literal newline).  GNU `sed` is able to insert newlines encoded as `\n` with `s///` like this.

```
$ sed 's/),(/),\n(/g' file
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF),
(AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF);
```

Using standard `sed`: This first "marks" where the newlines should go by inserting some other character (`@` used here, pick one that does not occur in the data).  These are then swapped out for newlines using `y///` (which *does* understand `\n` as newlines in non-GNU `sed`).

```
$ sed 's/),(/),@(/g; y/@/\n/' file
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF),
(AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF);
```

The above could also have been written as `sed 's/),(/),@(/g' file | tr '@' '\n'`.

Using standard `sed`, but encoding the newline as `\n` and then getting the shell to insert a literal newline in its place using a "C-string" (`$'...'`, available in some shells):

```
$ sed $'s/),(/),\\\n(/g' file
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF),
(AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF);
```

See the very end for "totally standard" variant of the above.

Using `awk`: This reformats the given data from a record with fields delimited by `),(` to a record with fields delimited by `),\n(`, and then ooutputs the reformatted data.

```
$ awk -F '[)],[(]' -v OFS='),\n(' '{ $1 = $1; print }' file
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF),
(AAAA, BBBB, CCCC),
(DDDD, EEEE, FFFF);
```

The pattern used as input field delimiter, `[)],[(]`, could also be written as `\\),\\(`.  You need the double backslashes to escape the backslash that escapes the parentheses.  You really only need this in front of the `(`, but I use it in front of both for symmetry (and it won't break anything; `\)` just matches a `)` anyway).  If you don't like symmetry, use either `),[(]` or `),\\(` instead.

We had to treat the `(` specially here as `awk` uses *extended* regular expressions (not *basic* ones that `sed` uses by default).

---

For completeness, since the question is tagged with [ed](/questions/tagged/ed)...

Using the `ed` editor, you can insert a newline after the comma in each occurrence of `),(` on a line using the command

```
g/INSERT INTO/ s/),(/),\
(/g
```

(That final `\` on the first line escapes the newline character.)

This applies the `s///g` command to all lines containing the string `INSERT INTO`, and it inserts a literal newline after each comma between two parentheses.

You could do something similar with standard `sed`.  From the command line:

```
sed '/INSERT INTO/ s/),(/),\
(/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Kusalananda. I used the comand `sed` and this was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: @Kekevalde22 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).